# Untracking directories with Git-SVN

Tags: git, git-svn

Let's imagine that I have a very big (> 1Gb) SVN repository, I check it out in full with `git svn` but then decides that I want to stop tracking some directories / files on the "git side", that is, not tracking locally and not pushing when I push the branch to a remote.

I imagine that deleting those with `git rm` would work, however, my question is: does this break things for git-svn or will git-svn still be able to update from SVN?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a sparse clone in a separate local Git repository, as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517784/unignore-directories-in-git-svn-adding-directories-to-a-sparse-checkout), with [`git svn clone --include-path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt---include-pathsltregexgt).

Anything else would change the checksum of the existing revision (if you used git filter-branch) or would `dcommit` a deletion (if you use `git rm`)

Or you could [mark the directory as ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22552349/6309), adding the [`.gitignore` to the Subversion repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22330931/6309), for others to also ignore the same folder.